# How to get all navigation controllers to root in tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app which has three tabs in tab bar controller .Each tab bar item has a navigation controller  and there is a log out button on first tab bar item.Now if i navigate into different naigation controllers and log out then all the navigation controllers remain in the same state for new user.I want all the navigation controleers to get to root when users logs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your prob can be solved by writing a method for logging out and the method pops all the view controllers added to the root controller.when the user taps on the logout button all the view controllers should be popped and if needed call the action in all the three view controllers.

hope it would work..

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
for (UINavigationController *navController in myViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Where to put this code ihavt done anything to navigation controller with code .I have used it directly from xib

Comment: Anywhere, perhaps in your log out button action, where "myViewController" would be `self`.

Answer (score 1):

jtbandes, your answer works really well, but what if I need to push the root view controller for only one tab? I don't want other tabs to be modifier, I just need to push the root view controller of one tab.

Comment: For the record: just answered my own question. The answer is:


    UINavigationController *navig = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];  --> replace "3" with the index of the tab you want to refresh.